# How many coils I have to cut from a spring do to change it from 18 Joule to 10 Joule

Tags: physics

In spring-powered airguns you calculate the effect in Joule.

I would like to change the spring in my airrifle but where I live the legal limit is 10 Joule and I bought a 18 Joule spring (there are no 10 Joule springs for sale).

This spring is 337 mm long and has 41 coils. I would like to calculate how many coils I have to remove to still be legal.

I tried to understand it myself from this page: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pespr.html
The potential energy in a spring is this:
$$
PE=\frac{1}{2}kx^2 
$$
where k is the spring constant and x is the displacement.

So I thought like this:

$$
18=\frac{1}{2}kx^2 
$$
$$
10=\frac{1}{2}kx^2 
$$

Assumption: $k$ is the same because it is the same spring (?). So in other words the $x$ must be a different value to make the equation system work if I assume that the displacement is numbered in coils and is the spring is zero length.

So I put the nr of coils (41) from the bought string as $x$ in the first and solve for $k$:

$$
18=\frac{1}{2}k41^2 => 36 = k * 1681 => k = 36/1681
$$

$$
10=\frac{1}{2}kx^2 => 20 = k * x^2 => \sqrt{\frac{20}{\frac{36}{1681}}} = x => x=30.559 => x = 30
$$

So I have to have 30 coils left (so I remove 11)

What do you think? are my assumptions and calculations correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You put the number of coils for the displacement which has a unit?

Comment: And to be legal, you should round $30.559$ to $30$ and not $31$.

Comment: The approach looks good to me (don't show this to your physics teacher, though! The answer is correct but the notation is sketchy). I would leave $30$ coils, as Fakemistake points out.

Comment: It depends on how the compression $\Delta x$ of the coil is attained / limited

Comment: @Fakemistake I know, my approach is VERY sketchy but I only need a rough guide.